# issue with bitbucket pull request

Tags: bitbucket, pull-request

I create a new branch from master, after push code to this branch when I go to pull request section I create pull request and specified my branch and destination branch when I click on pull request button I recive "unrelated branches" error while I get this branch from master.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oh...
I push my codes before pulling destination code, this error comes from here.
for example if you create a branch from master , you should to first pull master to your folder then push all things.